# send command via php

Tags: php, url, header, command

I have a webpage index.php from where I would like to send a command through another url but without going to this page.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$nb = $_GET[‘value’];

if ($nb >= 1000)
    header('Location: http://ipaddress/.../?command=on');

else if $nb >= 500 && $nb < 1000)
    header('Location: http://ipaddress/.../?command=middle');

else 
header('Location: http://ipaddress/.../?command=off');
?>
```

The problem is that the page tries to change due to the “header”, I just would like to send the command but to stay on my page index.php
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: By sending `header('Location: ...')` you are implicitly reloading the page. When you say "sending a command" what exactly do you mean? Reading between the lines, I think you might be after some form of AJAX functionality...

Comment: I would like to do the same action than visiting the url `http://ipaddress/.../?command=on` but I want my index page to stay displayed (or eventually reload)

Comment: And you want to do this by, for example, clicking a button or link on the page, but without reloading the page?

Comment: Actually I would do it automatically at the loading of the page, depending of the value of the GET.
I will try all your solutions, I let you know the result

Answer (score 4):

### Use `curl`

You need to use [`curl` (man page)](http://php.net/curl) for this.

### POST Example

For example to post a command on to the page you would use:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://ipaddress');

$data = array('command' => 'middle');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

### GET example

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://ipaddress?command=middle');   
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

### Preventing the requested URL's content from being output to screen

You need to look at the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option of `curl_setopt()`. For example:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://ipaddress?command=middle');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Now `$return` contains the content fromthe requested URL

### Documentation

The options used in `curl_setopt()` are [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: This will change the behaviour though: The request will no longer be made from the user's browser. If the command requires the user to be logged in, things will no longer work.

Comment: Agreed, but that was not mentioned. The requirement was simply: _to send a command through another url but without going to this page_. Also authentication can be sent over with the `curl` request if needs be.

Comment: @Pekka this is the very reason I upvoted your answer earlier BTW! :)

Comment: @Treffynnon yeah, chances are this is the best way to go. I just thought it worth mentioning (to prevent a follow-up question later :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's fine that it's the *server* doing the call, use e.g. `file_get_contents()` to send the command.

If  you need the client to make the request, you could e.g. serve an `img` or `iframe` element and load the target URL into that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, use file_get_contents instead:

```
<?php
$nb = $_GET[‘value’];

if ($nb >= 1000)
    file_get_contents('http://ipaddress/.../?command=on');

else if $nb >= 500 && $nb < 1000)
    file_get_contents('http://ipaddress/.../?command=middle');

else 
    file_get_contents('http://ipaddress/.../?command=off');
?>
```

Comment: This will change the behaviour though: The request will no longer be made from the user's browser. If the command requires the user to be logged in, things will no longer work.

Comment: A change in behaviour is required in the question! If the request must come from the user's browser, then my solution is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use Ajax for that. Ajax is better than cURL or file_get_contents since you will stay on your page, exactly where you are.

```
function SendData(strData)
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            // The page has been requested and your code has been run
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://ipaddress/.../?command=" + strData, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Call it with HTML:
`<a href='#' onClick='SendData("on");'>Send ON</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, by setting up a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) session from your script - but don't you rather want to include the file and call a function or something?

Comment: Well, since it looks like it's an (asynchronous) API-call, CURL could be the way to go. You don't want to include the script, just call it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should look at using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php).

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() for GET request or cURL for GET and POST requests

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

`$resp = file_get_contents('http://ggg.com?foo=bar');`

Check out the PHP manual for file_get_contents and fopen which have wrappers for fetching http content, enabled by default in most builds.

You can even POST using this method without having to use additional libraries like cURL. If you think this functionality might be useful to you, have a look at stream_get_contents in the PHP manual.